# absolute positioned image zoom not working properly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to zoom a image which is inside a div.

When page is loaded i am showing **300*300 size image** inside a **400*400 size div**.

So, to show the image at the center of the div i am using the following css.

```
#img1{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

with the above css code i can able to show the image at the center of the div.

but when a user clicks on zoom button i am increasing the height and width of the image. If it becomes **600*600 size image**, i have to show scroll bar so the user can scroll the div to show the full image.

For this i set **overflow:auto** to div.

But the problem is i can't see the full image when i scroll the div. This may be due to the **position:absolute** property of image. How can i fix this.

I created a fiddler also. There i am showing 2 divs before and after zooming image. Please check.

http://jsfiddle.net/codingsolver/L4qdL/1/

Comment: Because you've set your `outer` class to a fixed size (400px)?

Comment: Yes. But i set overflow to auto for that class right ?

Comment: @Ranadheer when image sizes increase, container div sizes expand also, you want?

Comment: @midstack. No i have to show fixed div. size of div is fixed. And image size is variable depends on zoomIn/zoomOut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this;

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <img id="img1" src="http://siliconangle.com/files/2012/04/HTML5_Wallpaper_1680x1050.png" />
    </div>
</div>
<button class="zoomout" data-zoom="out">Zoom Out</button > 
<button class="zoomin" data-zoom="in">Zoom In</button >
```

**CSS**

```
.outer{
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    margin:30px;
    text-align:center;
}

.inner {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

img {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L4qdL/7/