# How can I zoom part of image in html?

Tags: html

How can I zoom part of image in html?I want to zoom just a selected part of image. Let's say I want a way to display just the the center 120X80px of an image that's 320px × 480px in HTML. After that I want to zoom it.How can I do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883094/absolute-positioned-image-zoom-not-working-properly

Comment: You'll need to use CSS too, or is that too much? Heh

Comment: @LukePark can you help me to writ the css coad that you say,please

Comment: Alternatively, you could use Google to find the information  yourself.  It's been documented more times than I can count.